# dynamically changing url to reset to default view

Tags: javascript, jquery, location-href

I have been attempting to write code to dynamically change a particular href value to the current url. It works to a point, but the problem is that on my page I have a few different filters, so when one is clicked, the current url is then overridden.

is there a way to grab the first url as a variable when the page loads and keep it the same until someone leaves the page ?

I've been experimenting with various conditional statements but not had much luck.

The code that works is this one :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currenturl = document.URL;
    $("#reset").attr("href", currenturl);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could store the initial url as a cookie.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";path=/";
    }

    function getCookie(cname) {
      const name = cname + "=";
      const ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          let c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
              c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
              return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
      }
      return "";
    }
  
    setCookies('INITIAL_URL', document.URL);
  
    $("#reset").attr("href", getCookie('INITIAL_URL'));
  
});
```

And then use some logic when you need to reset the cookie value.

Comment: Brill, thanks for that! Can you point me in the direction on some good documentation on how to reset cookies? still very much new to all this but want to learn :)

Comment: You can reset a cookie by just settings its value to null. setCookies('INITIAL_URL', null).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp is a good starting point. If this has solved your issues can you mark as answer. Thanks :)

Comment: I think it's definitely a step in the right direction, but not working. the console error says - setCookies is not defined.

Comment: Ah think it was a typo - setCookie rather than setCookies. It's very close in that the filters aren't causing trouble , but the url isn't initially being changed -